# AngularJS ng-repeat set size according to number of repeats

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ng-repeat that creates div for each occurrence.
I want to set the size in % dynamically that it will spread through the whole parent element.

Something like:

```
ng-repeat="widget in widgets" 
style="display:inline-block;
       border:none;width:100/{{widgets.length}}%"
```

And I want to do it in my html and not in js

Is it at all possible?

Comment: is your style according to some value in widgets? I mean is the width dependent on it?

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-style , [ngStyle in angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

```
<div ng-repeat="widget in widgets" >
<span ng-style="{display:'inline-block', 
       border:'none', width:100/widgets.length+'%'}" </span>
</div>
```

Detailed explanation : [ng-style in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364445/apply-css-style-attribute-dynamically-in-angular-js)

**Update** :

```
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" ng-style="{width: item.value+'%'}" >
```

Check the first check box and see the style applied for the image : [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JanakiSathya/7nwwm5uk/)

Comment: Thanks!
I'm having a hard time running this though, it evaluates wrong or something.
I tried changing it to:
ng-style="{'display':'inline-block', 'border':'none','width':100/{{widgets.length}} + '%'}"

since angular expects there , instead of ; but still nothing.

Any ideas?