# AngularJS bind CSS value through ng-click. Value located in object in controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, data-binding

[Here is a Codepen link](http://codepen.io/drewbeh/pen/ZQabNq)

I have multiple buttons that change a CSS attribute for text color. I am able to get this working using static values such as 'blue' or 'red', but I want to access hex code values which are saved in an object within my controller.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <input type="button" value="blue" ng-style="{color: 'blue'}" 
    ng-click="myColor = { color:'blue' }">
  <div ng-repeat="person in people" ng-style="myColor">
    Name: {{ person.name }} <br>
    Birth Year: {{ person.birth }}<p>
  </div>
</body
```

Here is my controller

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.colors = [
  { color: 'b1', value: '#000000' },  //black
  { color: 'b2', value: '#000099' },  //blue
  { color: 'r1', value: 'ff0000' },   //red
  { color: 'y1', value: '#ffff00' }   //yellow
];

$scope.people = [
  { name: 'Abraham Lincoln', birth: '1809' },
  { name: 'Benjamin Franklin', birth: '1706' },
  { name: 'George Washington', birth: '1732' }
];

})
```

I want to change

```
ng-click="myColor = { color:'blue' }"
```

to something along the lines of

```
ng-click="myColor = { color:'colors[1].value' }
```

Comment: was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

You could call this by calling function on `ng-style`

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="person.color = colors[$index].color" ng-style="{color: person.color}">
    Name: {{ person.name }} <br>
    Birth Year: {{ person.birth }}<p>
</div>
```

> Not sure which color should be binding to which `person`, so I took color based on index

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ngStyle docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle):

> Expression which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys. Since some CSS style names are not valid keys for an object, they must be quoted.

So you could change it to:

```
ng-click="myColor = { 'color':colors[1].value }
```

I found this while searching too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364563/643779

Answer (score 0):

Just use it this way:

```
<input type="button" value="blue" ng-style="{color: 'blue'}" 
     ng-click="myColor = {color: colors[1].value}">

<input type="button" value="red" ng-style="{color: 'red'}" 
     ng-click="myColor = {color: colors[2].value}">

<input type="button" value="yellow" ng-style="{color: 'yellow'}" 
     ng-click="myColor = {color: colors[3].value}">
```