# Show a square with different background for every option in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have this model:

```
"PRIORITY": [{
            "id": 651,
            "label": "Haute",
            "colorCode": "#ff001e",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "id": 652,
            "label": "Moyenne",
            "colorCode": "#ffbe33",
            "active": true
        }];
```

And I must show for every option a small square before label value with background-color: colorCode.

In view, I have this:

```
<select 
    class="full-width" 
    ng-model="dossier.priorityId" 
    ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in reference.PRIORITY"
    ng-disabled="dossier.statut !== 'EN_COURS_CREATION'" 
    epf-options-class>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

It's possible to do this in angular 1?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364445/apply-css-style-attribute-dynamically-in-angular-js

Comment: No, must be inside option, <option>box-style Option Label</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with options. You have to use custom directive or try [this](https://github.com/axel-zarate/js-custom-select) one, It is simple you just have to modify its template and directive.