# How to set background color for a div dynamically in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to angular. I'm getting the background color to be shown from a backend api. I want to set it as a div's background color:

I've tried:

```
<div style="background-color: {{vitalItem.value.color}}" >
```

but the color is not set. In console, it shows:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value background-color: #d9534f (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

Any help is appreciated..

EDIT:

Here's my html

```
<div class="latest-reading-box">
     <div class="latest-reading-container value-contain-type" ng-style="{'background-color': vitalItem.value.color}">
         <p class="p-time">{{vitalItem.value != null ? vitalItem.value.date : ""}}</p>
         <h3 class="latest-value">{{vitalItem.value != null ? vitalItem.value.value : ""}}</h3>
         <p class="type-value">{{vitalItem.value != null && vitalItem.value.vitalEntryType != 0 ?
                                                  getVitalEntryTypeName(vitalItem.value.vitalEntryType): ""}}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

In chrome's inspect, this is what see:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="latest-reading-container value-contain-type" ng-style="{'background-color': vitalItem.value.color}">
    <p _ngcontent-c1="" class="p-time">08 Jul, 2017</p>
    <h3 _ngcontent-c1="" class="latest-value">67</h3>
    <p _ngcontent-c1="" class="type-value"></p>
</div>
```

everything except vitalItem.value.color is showing their value. Why is ng-style not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use ng-style to achieve this

```
<div ng-style="{'background-color':vitalItem.value.color}" >
```

Comment: Ohh I thought u were trying to add style in class which is wrong syntax but if you want to add dynamically, you have to use ng-style

Comment: Flag as a duplicate would have been more efficient than answering this question. It has been asked many many times.

Comment: But the question OP asked was different initially, he was trying to add a style to a class dynamically and the later on he updated the question. And that's when I flagged it as a duplicate. The answerers here doesn't deserve a downvote as myself volunteered to answer this before OP updated the question . @Mistalis

Comment: @HeisenBerg Accept answer if it helped

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and [`<div ng-style="{'background-color': data.backgroundCol}"></div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364563/4927984)?

Comment: I agree that the answer is same as you described in your comment except the scope variable but it was different initially

Comment: Sorry, but its not working. In chrome inspect, this is what I see <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="latest-reading-container value-contain-type" ng-style="{'background-color':  vitalItem.value.color}">

Comment: What is vitalItem.value.color ?

Comment: vitalItem is a model that I've used in.component.ts

Comment: Can you print {{vitalItem.value.color}} in your template and see if it is printing?

Comment: I put it in place of vitalItem.value.date and its showing the color.. like #5cb85c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148887/discussion-between-vivz-and-heisenberg).

Comment: I think you are using angular 2
So use [ngStyle]

Comment: no I'm using angular 4

Comment: Same syntax for angular 2 and 4 for ng-style which is [ngStyle]

Comment: yes, that worked. Thank you.