# Navbar item highlight

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a question regarding navbars. I want to highlight a navbar item when I clicked an item but I don't know if I need to use angular or css for that. Can you guide me a little bit, please?

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/tasks" class="nav-link" href="#">Tasks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/newTask" class="nav-link" href="#">New task</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/users" class="nav-link" href="#">Users</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/newProject" class="nav-link" href="#">New Project</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AngularJS Highlight anchor tag when click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728027/angularjs-highlight-anchor-tag-when-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `routerLinkActive` which will add a css class that you can use for styling. So in the following code if the current route is `/newProject` the list item will be styled according to your `active` css class:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active">
  <a routerLink="/newProject" class="nav-link" href="#">New Project</a>
</li>
```

More information on `routerLinkActive` [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description).