# Angular 2 - Dynamically set image URL

Tags: html, angular, image

The image path is defined in item.imagePath.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
   <div style="background-image: url(item.imagePath)" class="thumb">
       <span>{{item.productName}}</span>
   </div>
   <div>
       <p>{{item.productFeature}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

`style="background-image: url(item.imagePath)"` 
What is the correct syntax as this does not work?

Comment: use **ng-style** More on link below [apply-css-style-attribute-dynamically-in-angular-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364445/apply-css-style-attribute-dynamically-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styles are updated according to the value of the expression evaluation:

keys are style names with an optional . suffix (ie 'top.px', 'font-style.em'),
values are the values assigned to those properties (expressed in the given unit).

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + photo + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
       <div class="thumb">
           <img src="{{item.imagePath}}" />
           <span>{{item.productName}}</span>
       </div>
       <div>
           <p>{{item.productFeature}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it seems like img src is workable if the path is absolute, item.imagePath that I have is relative, thus would require to generate the url (background-image:url). Do you have alternative?